# Как изменить координаты в Яндекс картах при адаптации под мобильные?

Tags: javascript, api, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Имеется вот такая инициализация яндекс карт с координатами центра, можно ли изменить координаты центра при изменении ширины окна браузера? (нужно для адаптации карты на мобилках)

```js
   ymaps.ready(init);
 var myMap,
  myPlacemark;

 function init() {
 myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
  center: [55.75399399999374,37.62209300000001],
  zoom: 16,
  controls: ["fullscreenControl"]
 });

 myMap.controls
  .add("trafficControl", {
   float: "left"
  })
  .add("zoomControl", {
   position: {
    left: 50,
    top: 100
   }
  })
  .add("geolocationControl", {
   float: "left"
  })

 myMap.controls.get("trafficControl").hideTraffic();
 myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

 myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.75399399999374,37.62209300000001], {
  hintContent: 'Some text',
  balloonContent: 'Some text'
 });
 myPlacemark.balloon.close();

 myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

У карты есть [методы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#methods-summary) для изменения центра и уровня зума. Можете по любой своей логике менять центр карты или устанавливать границы видимой области.

Вот тут есть пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/mapparams

Comment: Пожалуйста не размещайте голые ссылки. Приводите основной текст ответа на вопрос, а ссылки лишь как дополнение/указание источника.